# Использование перечислений enum

Tags: c++

Где эффективно можно использовать перечисления enum?

Comment: Здраствуйте, вот [ссылка](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/java/1488349.flat.aspx), здесь обсуждается немного не то, но **примеры** как-раз то что нужно **;)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enum представляет из себя набор связных констант. На основании этого, сразу становится ясно что лучше заводить для констант отдельный список

```
enum nums {ONE,TWO, THREE,FOUR};
```

чем просто объявлять целочисленные переменные так

```
const int one = 0,two = 1,three = 2,four = 3;
```

И уж во всяком случае, лучше чем это

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define THREE 3
#define Four 4
```

Также, c enum чтение кода становится более понятным например при передачи значений в функцию

```
int func(nums n, nums m);
```

Чем просто так

```
int func(const int n,const int m);
```

Конечно, можно определять свои значения констант

```
enum Params {WIDTH = 100, HEIGHT = 200};
```

И тогда очень удобно в различных участках кода, их группировать

```
enum room1 {LEFT = 20, RIGHT = 70, TOP = 50};
enum colors {RED = 5, GREEN = 20, BLACK = 50};
```

В общем, использование enum, добавит вашему коду понятность, красоту и читабельность.

Answer (score 2):

Основным достоинством перечислений является повышение читаемости кода. Поэтому эффективно использовать их там, где естественным образом возникают перечисления: описания дней недели, названий месяцев, и т.д. Интересные примеры по перечислениям: [C++ enums](http://www.quizful.net/post/enum-types-c).

Answer (score 1):

Там, где нужно создать последовательный ряд целочисленных констант, составляющих смысловую последовательность. На скорости выполнения программы они не оказывают существенного влияния по сравнению с обычными константами.

Comment: На скорости выполнения программы они не оказывают существенного влияния по сравнению с обычными константами.

 Слово "существенного" смущает. Может не оказывает никакого влияния?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы enum'ы не захламляли пространство имён, лучше подписывать начало типа к названию констант:

```
enum Color {Color_Red, Color_Green, Color_Blue};
Color gr=Color_Green;
```

Answer (score 0):

На перечислениях можно делать битовые маски смотри тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift примеры или гугли

> bitmask enum

Так же название говорит само за себя. Там где нужно ограниченное перечисление. Наприме в Unreal Engine мне потребовалось через Enum указывать какую ось 3d вектора изменять при нажатии определённой кнопки.

Есть перечисление

```
namespace EAxis
{
    enum Type
    {
        None,
        X,
        Y,
        Z,
        None,
        X,
        Y,
        Z,
    }
}
```

И я передавал значение в функции , например если нужно было изменить объект по оси X

```
.OnClicked(this, &FeditorModeEdModeToolkit::OnButtonAxis, EAxis::Type::X, 2)
```

Перечисления это константы и их хорошо оптимизирует компилятор